# multiple text direction in the same Textview component

Tags: android, textview, arabic, number-formatting

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

the text in the same Textview android , in the first image number is not formatted well 3/4 4
it is from Note 2

the next image from grand and format is well  4 3/4

how can i fix that in android to be the same as image 2 ??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this to format text from same `TextView`. You can use a lot of other html tags to achive what you need.

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("some text <b>other bold text</b>"));
```

Comment: problem not in bold , it is in direction of numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try using
    `textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);`
or
    `textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);`

Comment: but i want direction numbers in the text to be from left to right and direction words right to left so now i need two directions in the same text view

Comment: Why not make it 2 text views then? One for the numbers and one for the text.